# jquery show the related image on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash

i am developing a asite using html css jquery presently it is in flash .

http://www.minecraft-crafting.net/

as you can see in the website if we click on any image it shows the related image on header .

i can do it using jquery but the method is going so long .

i am trying to set display block and none on click of the tiles .

means if we click on lower tiles then it will set  disply:block of related tiles in header  and will set display :none of other 
please help me to make the script short.
using i and parameters

Comment: Onclick, `$('headerID').html($(this).data)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Container > img').on('click', function() {
    var a = $(this).attr(src);
    $('#header').css({'background-image': 'url("' + a + '")'});
});
```